# Set fix day and increment month/year in PHP date()

Tags: php

I have this problem where I need to output specific day and will increment month and year only. This is the sample problem

if the day today(2017-12-08 Y-m-D format) is less than the 15th day of the month then output must be

```
| DATE       |
| 2017-12-15 |
| 2017-12-30 |
| 2018-01-15 |
| 2018-01-30 |
| 2018-02-15 |
| 2018-02-28 |
```

Wherein the fixed day are the 15th and 30th only and no other dates except 28th of February. And the values that increments are the month and year only. With regards to February, it will only get the last day of the month (28 or 29 if leap year occurred).

Sorry for the confusing problem, hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: You will have to clarify your exact rules a bit more than that. It's always supposed to be the 15th and 30th? The 15th and the last day of the month but not more than the 30th? Or can that vary? Perhaps 16th and 31st? Have you tried anything that didn't work?

Comment: 15th and 30th day only. With the month of february having only 28 days, it'll just get the last day of february(the 28th). I have been trying some codes but nothing works.

Comment: What's the logic of your output and what's your problem? You don't know how to check if the date is 15th of the month or the last day of month, or are there different issue?

Comment: Thank you all. I got the code working now but it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $whatever; $i++) {
    $fifteenth = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12 + $i, 15, 2017 + floor($i / 12));
    echo date('Y-m-d', $fifteenth), PHP_EOL;
    echo date('Y-m-', $fifteenth), min(date('t', $fifteenth), 30), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `$whatever` in the loop condition is how many months in advance you want to print.
The `12` and `2017` in the `mktime` call are your starting month and year.

This directly creates a timestamp of the 15th of the month (as opposed to adding 1 month relatively to the last date, that's error prone), using `mktime` overflow date calculations (12 + 5 = 17 = May; note that that's an explicitly supported feature). It then uses `date('t')` to get the last day of the month and restricts it to a maximum of `30` using the simple `min` function.